# Datatables ajax sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

I´m having some trouble sorting an ajax datatable in ascending order, since the default value in mysql is either NULL or 0, and I don´t want to show them. For example, in my table I have:

```
item | value
-----+------
   a |     2
   b |     3
   c |     4
   d |  NULL
```

The descending order sort works well, however ascending will show 'd' first, and I don't want 'd' to be there. It also seems that a custom js order is not possible because since this is ajax, the order is done in the db directly.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think you are getting your technologies mixed up. The sort order that you are pulling from the table is dependent on your select case. Just because you put it into the table in 1 order doesn't mean it will come out that way. Ajax is just a method for communicating between the client and server so your title makes absolutely no sense. You can exclude values you do not want to show by your WHERE clause in the sql select statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can govern how null sorts in this way:

```
select item, value
from ...
order by case when value is null then 0 else 1 end descending,   -- or ascending (I do not full understud your question)
         value ascending                                         -- or descending (idem)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want d to be there filter it out.  `WHERE value IS NOT NULL`
Question doesn't make much sense, it would of been easier had you given us current records, current results, expected results.

Comment: I don't want to filter it out, I just want the null values not to be considered when sorting, but I DO WANT them in the table.

Answer (score 0):

When using server side call for Jquery DataTable you can solve the issue at the select statement used to populate the table using this order by clause:

`.order("case when "column_selected" is null then -9999999 else "column_selected" end "direction_sorted")`